# Extracting a value from an union

Tags: llvm

What is the LLVM way to extract values from an array of unions?
Unions are not directly supported and this seems to complicate things.

Background:
I am calling a function returned by the JIT execution machine
and pass it 1 argument, namely the base address of an array
of unions which contains the arguments.

The data structure is set up from C like:

```
std::array<union{int,float*}> arguments(5);
```

The sequence of occurences of `int` and `float*` is encoded
in a `vector<llvm::Type*>`:

```
i32
i32
float*
float*
float*
```

Right now I am trying this (this is the jitted function):

```
define void @main([8 x i8]* %arg_ptr) {
entrypoint:
   %0 = getelementptr [8 x i8]* %arg_ptr, i32 0
   %1 = getelementptr [8 x i8]* %arg_ptr, i32 1
   %2 = getelementptr [8 x i8]* %arg_ptr, i32 2
   %3 = getelementptr [8 x i8]* %arg_ptr, i32 3
   %4 = getelementptr [8 x i8]* %arg_ptr, i32 4
}
```

First of all, is the functions' signature correct (assuming
pointer size is 8 bytes)?

How do I get the first `i32` out of the `[8 x i8]` stored in %0?

Do I need to cast the array `[8 x i8]` first to a pointer `i32*`,
then create another GEP to its first element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that LLVM IR does not really have unions. What happens in practice is that Clang (which is aware of the target triple, so the details are platform/ABI specific) will create a single-element `struct` big enough to contain you union and act on that. Here's some C code:

```
typedef union {
  double dnum;
  int inum;
  float* fptr;
} my_union;

int bar(my_union* mu) {
  return mu[4].inum;
}
```

Converting this to LLVM IR with clang (using the default target on a x86-64 machine, we get this (optimized code, to reduce clutter):

```
%union.my_union = type { double }

define i32 @bar(%union.my_union* nocapture readonly %mu) #0 {
entry:
  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds %union.my_union* %mu, i64 4
  %inum = bitcast %union.my_union* %arrayidx to i32*
  %0 = load i32* %inum, align 4
  ret i32 %0
}
```

A few things to note here, with answers to some of the sub-questions embedded in your question:

- The union is replaced by the C type `struct {double}` because that's large enough to contain all union members, and it also provides the correct alignment constraints. LLVM knows absolutely nothing about unions. From this point on, it acts on a struct aggregate.
- Access to array members in LLVM is done with a GEP which gets two numeric indices. For an in-depth explanation of why it works this way, see http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html
- Once you have the member, you just load the value from it. Clang knows how members are laid out within an enum, so it loads a `i32*` directly from the member.

Comment: Nice idea to take a look what clang does. So it does the same up to %arrayidx and then does a bitcast. That's what I thought. The only thing not understood is `align 4`. We are in an 8 byte structure, this is naturally alligned to 8 bytes, right? Why would it add the alignment of 4 to the load instruction?

Comment: @wpunkt: note that the `load` acts on `i32*` so an alignment of 8 is not required, strictly speaking.